# Azure Dev Ops Publish Nuget Package add additional packages issue

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, azure-pipelines, nuget-package, azure-artifacts

I am new to dev ops pipelines and building nuget packages, however I have a C# repo in Azure Dev Ops,which has a pipeline which restores, builds, packs and then pushed the nuget package to the artifacts feed, now everything works with one exception.

Sometimes it uploads the dependencies, sometimes, it uploads just the dependencies liked in the .csproj file and sometimes it does all the dependencies including all the system and microsoft ones.

My pipeline code doesn't change.

Is this expected behaviour?
And can i prevent it?

I just makes my artifact feed a mess, instead of having one of two packages related to my project,it ends up with 100's, i would prefer all the dependencies in the nuget package.

any thoughts would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is an option when setting up to feed, 'Include packages from common public sources' if you uncheck this or remove the upstream feeds in the settings it sorts my issue.

Answer (score 0):

> Azure Dev Ops Publish Nuget Package add additional packages issue

If your project use the `packages.config` as nuget package managment, you could add the `IncludeReferencedProjects` to include all the dependencies:

nuget pack projectfile.csproj -IncludeReferencedProjects

If your project use the `PackageReference`  as nuget package managment, you could add the following `<ispack>true</ispack>` for each PackageReference to include them in the package.

And use the command line dotnet pack to create the package.